# How to workaround broken UIKeyboardLayoutGuide with Navigation Views?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios15

iOS 15 added the new and shiny `UIKeyboardLayoutGuide` to be able to put constraints on views that need to react with the keyboard.

This works great in a single view, but when you have constraints set up in *View A* and push *View B* onto the stack the keyboard layout guide suddenly gets a size of `CGRect.zero` (in *View A*).

When returning back to *View A* the keyboard layout guide frame is still `.zero` and thus the constraint between the keyboard layout guide *top* and *"SomeView".bottom* for example is broken.

To showcase the issue I added a green view to my tracking controller and a bottom constraint to the keyboard layout guide top anchor, like so:

```swift
let kbView = UIView()
kbView.backgroundColor = .green
kbView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.view.addSubview(kbView)

kbView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
kbView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
kbView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

kbView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

You can find the whole project in the link below on Github.

How can we workaround this issue and did someone else also experience this issue?
My current workaround is to write my own layout guide, which just works - and is compatible with iOS < 15.

Really, **this can't be true (?!)**, given the fact that this is a new and shiny feature...
Maybe I overlooked something...

Anyway: [Here is the demo project showcasing the issue](https://github.com/Fab1n/UIKeyboardLayoutGuide-UINavigationController-Test).

Comment: same problem here: keyboardLayoutGuide + navigationController = not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might just need to raise the threshold for those features to 15.4 https://twitter.com/kharrison/status/1506947828773498881

Comment: Thanks, this should be indeed the case.